# Пустой сайт cloudflare

Tags: apache2, cloudflare, domain

Я подключил домен к cloudflare по мимо основного домена я так же создал 2 поддомена поддомены работают прекрасно а с главным доменном сайта проблема при открытии страницы вместо содержимого сайта просто белый фон вывод консоли в инспекторе браузера:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

Как мне это исправить помогите пожалуйста

Сайт с которым проблема
https://shizaplay.ru

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему подключением Origin Certificates